# addEventListener does not fire on <li> in for loop

Tags: loops, addeventlistener

I've been searching the i-net now for 2 days and still can't find a solution for my problem so I want to ask you.

Background: I have a unordered list with list items and each li has an ::after element. I want to add a class to the li on click on the ::after Element.

Here is the important code:

```js
/* jslint browser: true */
/*global window */
window.onload = function() {


 //Possible Solution - 1st Try
var lit = document.getElementById("li1");

function showMe(){
    this.classList.add("in-view");
    console.log(this.className);
}
document.getElementById("li1").addEventListener("click", showMe.bind(this,lit),false);


// Possible Solution - 2nd Try
   var liitems = document.getElementsByClassName("liitems");
   
function pullTextOnClick() {
    liitems[i].classList.add("in-view");
    }
    
for (var i=0; i<liitems.length; i++) {
    liitems[i].addEventListener("click",pullTextOnClick, false);
}

};
```

```css
.timeline ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
    width:6px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:50px;
    background:#fff;
}

.timeline ul li::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom:0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: inherit;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <section class="timeline" id="timelineexpand">
        <ul>
            <li class="liitems" id="li1" onclick="showMe()">
                <div>
                    <time>1992</time>
                    Sth happend
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="liitems" id="li2">
                <div>
                    <time>1997</time>
                   Sth else
                </div>
            </li>
```

How I understand my problem and what I found out on the Internet:
The addEventListener opens the 2nd argument (eventHandler) with an object reference. Which is, when I log it with the console, often the "window" or "undefined". So I have to somehow tell the function (showMe or pullTextOnClick) what "this" is or which li-element to use.

I would prefer it, if the eventListener would be in the for loop and constantly checking if a li-Node was clicked. If this happens, the index of the li-element should be forwarded to the function, which then adds the class "in-view".

The problem: The function showMe/pullTextOnClick does not fire. If i add a console.log inside these functions, they don't log anything. Why is that?

So I hope that somebody can explain me why my code does not work or how to improve it. Thank you!

Summary of my Questions:

1. why is "/*global window*/ doing anything, and what? It is in comments, but if I don't add it, it says "window.onload" is not defined.
2. How to bind the eventTarget (li-element) to the eventHandler-fct (showMe, pullTextOnClick)?
3. how does the "bind"-fct work? I read many explanations, but still don't understand why my code does not work.
4. I tried to add a class with "addClass", but it said that the fct was not defined. It only works with classList.add., but why?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

I tried to click the li-element. BUT when i tried to do this, the parent-container was selected. Reason was, because the li-element had a z-index of -1. I did this to hide it behind an other picture. Lesson learned.